# Phonegap / AngularJS : can't get $apply() working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm training myself in mobile app development, and I'm currently develop a baby sleeptracker app, using Phonegap, Onsen UI and AngularJS.

At the initialization, users have to define if their baby is currently awake or asleep to start the tracker. I used a modal windows for that over the homepage. Once they click, I want to display a text on the homepage like 'Your baby is asleep' or 'Your baby is awake', depending on their choice.

The thing is I can't make the view updated after clicking on one of the buttons... I know this is an asynchronous request, so I have to use $apply() to restart the Angular digest cycle, but I can't make it works...

Here is my code :

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <title>Colette</title> 

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/onsen-css-components-blue-basic-theme.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css"/>

  <script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>    
  <script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script> 
  <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js "></script> 

  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
        // retrieve the DOM element that had the ng-app attribute
        var domElement = $('html');
        angular.bootstrap(domElement, ["app"]);
    }, false);
    var app = angular.module('app',['onsen']);
  </script>

  <script src="lib/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/utils.js"></script>
  <script src="home.js"></script>
  <script src="daily_stats.js"></script>
  <script src="history.js"></script>
  <script src="settings.js"></script>
</head>

<body>    

  <ons-sliding-menu
    menu-page="menu.html" main-page="home.html" side="left"
    var="menu" type="reveal" max-slide-distance="260px" swipable="true">
  </ons-sliding-menu>

</body>
</html>
```

Home.html (load by default):

```
<ons-modal id="welcome" ng-controller="home">
    <ons-row>
      <ons-col align="center">
        <h2>Welcome !</h2>
        To initialize the app,<br />please tell us if your<br />baby is currently
      </ons-col>
    </ons-row>
    <ons-row style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <ons-col align="right" size="40%">
        <ons-button ng-click="init(false)">ASLEEP</ons-button>
      </ons-col>
      <ons-col align="center" size="20%">OR</ons-col>
      <ons-col align="left" size="40%">
        <ons-button ng-click="init(true)">AWAKE</ons-button>
      </ons-col>
    </ons-row>
    <ons-row style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <ons-col align="center">
        Thanks !
      </ons-col>
    </ons-row>
</ons-modal>

<ons-page modifier="home" class="home" ng-controller="home">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
      <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
        <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
      </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center"><ons-icon icon="fa-home"></ons-icon> Home</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <ons-row style="margin-top: 100px;">
    <ons-col align="center">
      <h3 class="state">{{state}}<br />{{stateTime}}.</h3>
      <ons-button ng-click="toggleState()">{{button_value | uppercase}}</ons-button>
      <p class="tips">{{tips}}</p>
    </ons-col>
  </ons-row>
</ons-page>
```

Home.js (home controller):

```
/*
 * Home Controller
 */

app.controller('home', function($scope,$timeout,$http){

    $scope.appHash = "";
    $scope.button_value = "";
    $scope.state = "";
    $scope.stateTime = "";
    $scope.tips = "";
    $scope.awake = true;
    $scope.begin = new Date();
    $scope.records = new Array();

    $scope.init = function(awake){      
        if(awake){
            $scope.button_value = "asleep";
            $scope.state = "Your baby is awake";
            $scope.tips = "Click 'ASLEEP' when your baby start to sleep.";
            $scope.awake = true;
        }
        else{
            $scope.button_value = "awake";
            $scope.state = "Your baby is asleep";
            $scope.tips = "Click 'AWAKE' when your baby is awake.";
            $scope.awake = false;
        }       
        //menu.setMainPage('home.html');
        $scope.saveState();
        $('#welcome').hide();
        $scope.$apply();
    }   

    $scope.restore = function(){
        $scope.appHash = localStorage.getItem('appHash');
        $scope.button_value = localStorage.getItem('button_value');
        $scope.state = localStorage.getItem('state');
        $scope.tips = localStorage.getItem('tips');
        $scope.awake = localStorage.getItem('awake');
        $scope.begin = new Date(localStorage.getItem('begin'));
        $scope.records = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('records'));
    }

    $scope.saveState = function(){
        localStorage.setItem('button_value', $scope.button_value);
        localStorage.setItem('state', $scope.state);
        localStorage.setItem('tips', $scope.tips);
        localStorage.setItem('awake', $scope.awake);
        localStorage.setItem('begin', $scope.begin);
        localStorage.setItem('records', JSON.stringify($scope.records));        
    }


    if(localStorage.getItem('appHash') == null){
        $http.get(backendURL+'?method=addApp&id=1').
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                //response = JSON.parse(data);
                localStorage.setItem('appHash', data.result[0]);                
                $scope.appHash = data.result[0];
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.appHash = data.result[0];
            });
        $('#welcome').show();
    }
    else{
        $('#home').show();
        $scope.restore();
        $scope.refreshStateTime();
    }   

});
```

When one of the initial button has been cicked, the `init()` method is called with the good parameter. But the view is not updated..

I commented `menu.setMainPage('home.html');`, which was a temporary solution to reload the page.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm also quite new to these three technologies (Phonegap, Onsen UI and Angular.js), this app is a training at the moment.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each controller is a new instance, not a singleton. So you're updating the state of one controller through init(), but the ui you're trying to update is bound to the variables of another controller instance with it's own seperate $scope.

```
<ons-modal id="welcome" ng-controller="home">
    ...
</ons-modal>

<ons-page modifier="home" class="home" ng-controller="home">
...
</ons-page>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wU2itKfEJZ8JvdaVsRgZ?p=preview

One solution is to wrap your html in another tag and assign the controller to that. Then remove the two other existing controllers.

```
<div ng-controller="home">
    <ons-modal id="welcome">
        ...
    </ons-modal>

    <ons-page modifier="home" class="home">
    ...
    </ons-page>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wU2itKfEJZ8JvdaVsRgZ?p=preview